# Is there a non brute force based solution to optimise the minimum sum of a 2D array only using 1 value from each row and column

Tags: python, arrays, optimization

I have a 2 arrays; one is an ordered array generated from a set of previous positions for connected points; the second is a new set of points specifying the new positions of the points. The task is to match up each old point with the best fitting new position. The differential between each set of points is stored in a new Array which is of size n*n. The objective is to find a way to map each previous point to a new point resulting in the smallest total sum. As such each old point is a row of the matrix and must match to a single column.

I have already looked into a exhaustive search. Although this works it has complexity O(n!) which is just not a valid solution.

The code below can be used to generate test data for the 2D array.

```py
import numpy as np


def make_data():
    org = np.random.randint(5000, size=(100, 2))
    new = np.random.randint(5000, size=(100, 2))
    arr = []
    # ranges = []
    for i,j in enumerate(org):
        values = np.linalg.norm(new-j, axis=1)
        arr.append(values)
    # print(arr)  
    # print(ranges)
    arr = np.array(arr)
    return arr
```

Here are some small examples of the array and the expected output.

Ex. 1

```
1 3 5 
0 2 3 
5 2 6
```

The above output should return [0,2,1] to signify that row 0 maps to column 0, row 1 to column 2 and row 2 to column 1. As the optimal solution would b 1,3,2

In

The algorithm would be nice to be 100% accurate although something much quicker that is 85%+ would also be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google search terms: "weighted graph minimum matching". You can consider your array to be a weighted graph, and you're looking for a matching that minimizes edge length.

> The assignment problem is a fundamental combinatorial optimization problem. It consists of finding, in a weighted bipartite graph, a matching in which the sum of weights of the edges is as large as possible. A common variant consists of finding a minimum-weight perfect matching.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

> The Hungarian method is a combinatorial optimization algorithm that solves the assignment problem in polynomial time and which anticipated later primal-dual methods.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

I'm not sure whether to post the whole algorithm here; it's several paragraphs and in wikipedia markup. On the other hand I'm not sure whether leaving it out makes this a "link-only answer". If people have strong feelings either way, they can mention them in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. The Hungarian algorithm looks very much like the solution. After some googling around on this I found this scipy method scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment() which I think is a fully implemented version of the algorithm for python although I will need to test this further.